# pick directories of a project to be in a submodule git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules, directory-structure

I have a big project that structured in a modular way with some directories to be commonly used (coupled) with other modules, while other directories are module specific, for example:

```
Modules
├── Module
│   ├── Submodule
│   │   ├── BaseClasses
│   │   ├── Config
│   │   ├── Console
│   │   ├── Database
│   │   │   ├── factories
│   │   │   ├── Migrations
│   │   │   └── Seeders
│   │   ├── Enums
│   │   ├── Events
│   │   ├── Http // private
│   │   │   ├── Controllers
│   │   │   ├── Middleware
│   │   │   ├── Requests
│   │   │   └── Transformers
│   │   ├── Interfaces
│   │   ├── Models
│   │   ├── Policies
│   │   ├── Providers
│   │   ├── Repositories // private
│   │   ├── Routes
│   │   ├── Tests // private
│   │   │   ├── Feature
│   │   │   └── Unit
│   │   └── Types
│   └── Submodule
│       ├── Config
│       ├── Console
│       ├── Database
│       │   ├── factories
│       │   ├── Migrations
│       │   └── Seeders
│       ├── Http // private
│       │   ├── Controllers
│       │   ├── Middleware
│       │   ├── Requests
│       │   └── Transformers
│       ├── Interfaces
│       ├── Models
│       ├── Policies
│       ├── Providers
│       ├── Repositories // private
│       ├── Resources
│       │   ├── assets
│       │   ├── lang
│       │   └── views
│       ├── Routes
│       └── Tests // private
│           ├── Feature
│           ├── Providers
│           ├── Responses
│           └── Unit
```

Repositories, Http, and Tests directories are private directory to a module.

I want to have a main git repository, where all modules are stores, excluding the private directories, and then a git submodule repository for each module (not submodule) private directories.

That is, when I give access to a developer, he should only see the common directories. Only the one with authorized access to that module private repository should be allowed to see the private directories.

how to do that using Git?

Using git submodules on a Module will move all the folders under that Module to the new git submodule repository, I want to pick what directories to be on the main repo, and what directories to be submodule repository.

Answer (score 0):

Replace each private directory with a symlink into a corresponding subdirectory of a private submodule you're about to create, then have that one main-project submodule contain all corresponding private directories those symlinks point to.